# increasing property of the heat equation on the interval

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

$Q_T^l=\{(x,t); 0<x<l, 0<t\leq T\}$,

$u_l\in C^{2,1}(Q_T^l)\cap C(\bar Q_T^l)$ is the solution of $\frac{\partial u_l}{\partial t}-a^2\frac{\partial^2u_l}{\partial x^2}=f(x,t), (x,t)\in Q_T^l$,

$u_l|_{t=0}=\varphi(x), 0\leq x\leq l$,

$u_l(0,t)=g_1(t), u_l(l,t)=0, 0\leq t\leq T$,

where $f\leq 0, \varphi(x)\geq 0, g_1(x)\geq 0$. Show that $u_l$ is increasing, that is, for $\lambda<\mu < l$, $u_\lambda(x,t)\leq u_\mu(x,t)$.

At first glance, let $v_l(y,t)=u_l(ly,t)$, all defined on $[0,1]\times [0,T]$. But $v_{l,t}-a^2/l^2 v_{l,xx}=f(x,t)$, with different $a^2/l^2$ for different $l$. So $$w=v_{\lambda}(x,t)-v_{\mu}(x,t)$$ solve a linear parabolic equation with a source term like $a^2(1/\lambda^2-1/\mu^2)u$. What to do then? Maximum principle could not be applied.

As  leo monsaingeon suggested, perhaps we need $f\geq 0$, so in $\partial_pQ_T^\lambda$, $u_\lambda\leq u_\mu$. But then what to do next? The $u_\lambda, u_\mu$ satifies different heat equations.

Comment: Are you sure $f\leq 0$? If $f\geq 0$ then $u_\mu(\lambda,t)\geq 0=u_\lambda(\lambda,t)$ so the maximum principle in $Q^\lambda_T$ allows to conclude.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Yes, in the problem, it is $f\leq 0$. How to apply the maximum principle, if let $f\geq 0$.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Thanks. The problem states wrong. Just $f\geq 0$.

Comment: If indeed $f\geq 0$ please amend the post accordingly! I'll comment below for a sketch of answer, but I vote to close this post as it is not really research level, it looks more like a problem/exercise that you were asked to solve for a class. Try posting instead to Math.StackExchange

Comment: Apply the MP a first time to $u_\mu$ on $Q^\mu_T$ to conclude that $u_\mu\geq 0$ everywhere, in particular also at $x=\lambda\in$. Applying the MP a second time to $v:=u_\mu-u_\lambda$ in $Q^\lambda_T$, with now $v=0$ on the left boundary and $v=u_\mu-0\geq 0$ on the right boundary (by the first step), allows to conclude that $v\geq 0$ as needed.